# How to clear out existing password on Windows command line in order to use personal access token

Tags: git, github

GitHub users still using passwords to access remote repos will no doubt have received the notification that GitHub is deprecating this in favour of personal access tokens. However, before one can use a PAT, one must first clear out the stored password so that the Git command prompts for it. Whilst there is help on how to do this on MacOS using keychain in the GitHub help pages, I can find no advice for doing this on Windows.

I note that git has various `credentials` and `credentials-helper` subcommands but I cannot find any detailed documentation on how to use them on the windows command line.

Could anyone give a clear explanation of how to do this and what options one has access to (say for storing more than one PAT)?

Answer (score 1):

The [Git FAQ explains how to do this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager):

```
$ echo url=https://author@github.com | git credential reject
```

This should work on all operating systems, although the Git Credential Manager for Windows (not Git Credential Manager Core) had a bug that prevented this from working in some cases.  I believe the syntax above works even there, but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the way to do it (on my machine) is via

`control panel/user accounts/credential manager`

and then click on `windows credentials`. Then scroll down until one finds the `git:https//github.com` entry and edit this, pasting the PAT into the password field.

This seems to work OK but since I didn't set my password this way in the first place, I was hoping to find some git commands to do it all.

I have also noticed that when I push to a remote, I get a `credential-erase is not a git command` message, so it looks like the credential manager is issuing some command at this point.